# Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this Qlik Sense expression

Tags: if-statement, logic, logical-operators, qliksense, qlik-expression

```
LOAD
   if(Year(max(FISCAL_YEAR))=Year(Today()),
   Year(max(FINANCIAL_YEAR))) as Curr_FY,

   if(Year(max(FISCAL_YEAR))=Year(Today()),
   Year(today()-1)) as Prev_FY
   Resident [data_table];

   Let Current_FY = '=Curr_FY';
   Let Last_FY = '=Prev_FY';
```

I want to create Dynamic variable for current  FISCAL_YEAR and last FISCAL_YEAR

Comment: Can anyone help me for this solution ? It's really and urgent requirement

Answer (score 0):

If the table contains only a single value for `Curr_FY` and `Prev_FY` then you can use [peek script function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/May2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm) to get the value in a variable

```
Let Current_FY = peek('Curr_FY');
Let Last_FY = peek('Prev_FY');
```

Bear in mind that if there are multiple values then `peek` will return the last loaded value